# How to save Card on Stripe Dashboard?

Tags: stripe-payments

Here is code I use currently:

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script> 
<button id="stripeButton" class="button primary" type="button" style="width:238px;font-size:25px;border:0;height:46px">PAY NOW</button>
<script> 
  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({{ 
    key: 'pk_test_5....d7qE5A',
    locale: 'auto', 
    billingAddress: true, 
    allowRememberMe: true, 
    token: function(token) {{ 
      // here I send token.id to server and there (on server), I'm using curl and send this:
      // amount=9900&currency=usd&description=Signup&source=token.id
      // to https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges
      // inside token, I see "card_1Mx1LjG3jtPLuTF7vsiwlLND" - can I use it somehow?
    } 
  }); 
  document.getElementById('stripeButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {{ 
    // Open Checkout with further options: 
    handler.open({{ 
      name: 'My business', 
      description: 'Signup', 
      amount: 9900 
    }); 
    e.preventDefault(); 
  }); 
  // Close Checkout on page navigation: 
  window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {{ 
    handler.close(); 
  }); 
</script>
```

I do not need to re-use the card, I just want to store it and see card number on Dashboard (instead of last 4 number).
Thank you.

Comment: How are you currently creating these card objects? Can you provide your Stripe code for that? Attaching the source to a customer is how it will show up in the dashboard, so you likely need to modify your process to be able to do that. https://stripe.com/docs/api/sources/attach

Comment: I edited code so you can see what I do now. Stripe dialog is displayed and once Stripe check everything, token.id is returned and using cUrl on server, I send it to Stripe (like you can see on my code) and it works fine. Like you can see, I can get "card_1M..." and how should I attach it to customer? Or is there other way to store card number? Thanks!

Comment: Ah you are using Legacy Checkout. If you are just starting out, I would recommend using the current stripe flow for taking a payment and saving the card instead: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment

Comment: With that flow, you create a payment intent to take the payment. You can set `setup_future_usage` on a payment intent to tell Stripe to save the payment method for future on session or off session use https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/update#update_payment_intent-setup_future_usage

Comment: I solved it like this: first, I filter customers, and if customer does not exist, I add it. If it exists, I use they cus_id. Then, I create card using cus_id and tok_id. It works perfect. Just curious why Stripe did not posted some very simple, basic steps for all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this: first, I filter customers, and if customer does not exist, I add it. If it exists, I use they cus_id. Then, I create card using cus_id and tok_id (returned by my previous code). It works perfect. Just curious why Stripe did not posted some very simple, basic steps for all scenarios.